# Is polymorphism with an interface legal just as how polymorphism with an abstract class is legal?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

For example:

Say you have an **abstract** class called Animal, and a non-abstract class called Dog.
This is legal:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

But if you have an **interface** called Car and a normal class called Toyota would the same be legal?

```
Car car = new Toyota();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you compile that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is legal.

In your case, Dog must extend Animal:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}
```

The same is true with an interface (which is abstract by definition), and a class which implements it:

```
interface Car {}

class Toyota implements Car {}
```

Comment: Nice it helps you. On Stackoverflow you could give [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to people's helpful answers to thank them 

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it's legal as long as Toyota implements Car.

Comment: And `Dog` must extend `Animal`.